# Example of implicit function theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to understand implicit function theorem, so I came up with an example myself:

Let's define: $f:{\mathbb R}^2\times{\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R}^2, (a,b,c,d)\to (ad,bc)$. Let $(a_0,b_0,c_0,d_0)$ be a point such that $f(a_0,b_0,c_0,d_0)=0$ and $df(c_0,d_0)=0$. Then we have: $a_0d_0=0,b_0c_0=0,a_0b_0=0$. Take this point to be $(1,1,0,0)$. By implicit function theorem, we can locally solve $f(a,b,c,d)=0$  for $(c,d)$ in terms of $(a,b)$. What is this function? Any hints?

Comment: The condition is not $df(c_0, d_0) = 0$; you need the derivative to have full rank (in this case, rank two).

Comment: It doesn't seem like $df(c_0, d_0)$ even makes sense -- you should be evaluating at a point of the domain, $\mathbb{R}^4$ and getting a linear map $\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^2$. I suspect you're looking at the Jacobian and trying to place the condition on the second two columns, so what you really want is for the determinant $ab$ to be nonzero; your given point does work for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think what you find is that nearby the level set looks like $(a, b, 0, 0)$; this works for any $ab \neq 0$. So the implicitly defined function is zero.